# dropdown Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium with Chrome and I stuck at selecting a value from a dropdown. The markup I can obtain from the webpage itself:

```
<div class="col-sm-8  select-month  no-margin-bottom no-padding-left form-group select-container">
<select class="selectarea form-control select-month bs-select-hidden" id="month_start" name="month_start" title="Bitte wählen">
    <option class="bs-title-option" value="">Bitte wählen</option>
        <option id="month_start1" value="1">Januar</option>
        <option id="month_start2" value="2">Februar</option>
        <option id="month_start3" value="3">März</option>
        <option id="month_start4" value="4">April</option>
        <option id="month_start5" value="5">Mai</option>
        <option id="month_start6" value="6">Juni</option>
        <option id="month_start7" value="7" selected="selected">Juli</option>
        <option id="month_start8" value="8">August</option>
        <option id="month_start9" value="9">September</option>
        <option id="month_start10" value="10">Oktober</option>
        <option id="month_start11" value="11">November</option>
        <option id="month_start12" value="12">Dezember</option>
</select>

<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select selectarea form-control select-month open">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="month_start" title="Juli" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">Juli</span>&nbsp;
            <span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 489.688px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 64px;">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 487.688px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 62px;">
            <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
                <span class="text">Januar</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                </a></li><li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
                <span class="text">Februar</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">März</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">April</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Mai</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="6"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Juni</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="7" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Juli</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="8"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">August</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="9"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">September</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="10"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Oktober</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="11"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">November</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="12"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Dezember</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li></ul></div></div></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8  select-year  do_not_break_visible_hint no-margin-bottom no-padding-left form-group select-container"><select class="selectarea form-control select-year bs-select-hidden" id="year_start" name="year_start" title="Bitte wählen" style=""><option class="bs-title-option" value="">Bitte wählen</option>
        <option id="year_start2016" value="2016" selected="selected">2016</option><option id="year_start2017" value="2017">2017</option><option id="year_start2018" value="2018">2018</option><option id="year_start2019" value="2019">2019</option><option id="year_start2020" value="2020">2020</option><option id="year_start2021" value="2021">2021</option><option id="year_start2022" value="2022">2022</option><option id="year_start2023" value="2023">2023</option><option id="year_start2024" value="2024">2024</option><option id="year_start2025" value="2025">2025</option><option id="year_start2026" value="2026">2026</option><option id="year_start2027" value="2027">2027</option><option id="year_start2028" value="2028">2028</option><option id="year_start2029" value="2029">2029</option><option id="year_start2030" value="2030">2030</option><option id="year_start2031" value="2031">2031</option><option id="year_start2032" value="2032">2032</option><option id="year_start2033" value="2033">2033</option><option id="year_start2034" value="2034">2034</option><option id="year_start2035" value="2035">2035</option><option id="year_start2036" value="2036">2036</option>
                </select><div class="btn-group bootstrap-select selectarea form-control select-year"><button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="year_start" title="2016"><span class="filter-option pull-left">2016</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open"><ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu"><li data-original-index="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2016</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2017</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2018</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="4"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2019</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="5"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2020</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="6"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2021</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="7"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2022</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="8"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2023</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="9"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2024</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="10"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2025</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="11"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2026</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="12"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2027</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="13"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2028</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="14"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2029</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="15"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2030</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="16"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2031</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="17"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2032</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="18"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2033</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="19"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2034</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="20"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2035</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="21"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2036</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li></ul></div></div></div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using this code to select the value:

```
new SelectElement(chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("month_start"))).SelectByText("Dezember");
```

However, it says the following

> Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Which leads me to the conclusion that the first part from the HTML markup (`option class=bs-title-option`) is not the right one. Anyway, how to handle this??

Comment: How does the definition of bs-title-option class looks like?

Comment: how may I understand, @cezarypiatek?

Comment: I'm asking about css definition of given class. I've made mistake and asked you about bs-title-option  instead of  bs-select-hidden. Please provide css definition (rules) of  bs-select-hidden class.

Comment: This is a foreign webpage, where would I find the css file you exactly need?

Comment: I found it in the css file, but what section to copy?

Comment: All sections related to .bs-select-hidden selector

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your script right before this line of code and look at the page. Do you see the dropdown that you are trying to access? It may actually be hidden. It may also be that it just hasn't loaded completely yet or you may need to click something else to make it visible. We can't see any of that without the site link or more info from you.

Comment: I assume that there is an overlay that simulates "fancy-styled" dropdown. That overlay hides the real select and prevents selenium from accessing its. The "bs-select-hidden" class may indicate that the real select is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real dropdown on your application is generated by bootstrap library. You have to click at the button and select the item from list inside dropdown menu. See an example below:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(d => !d.FindElement(By.Id("busy")).Displayed);

// Click first month
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".bootstrap-select.select-month > button")).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
string targetMonth = "Februar";
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'" + targetMonth + "')]/..").Click();

// Click project type
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[data-id='projecttype']")).Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
string targetType = "In-house project";
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'" + targetType + "')]/..").Click();
```

Comment: what do I need to change to make it properly work? I marked it as correct answer, as it - so far - does the right thing. It only doesnt find this bootstrap select...

Comment: @JOHN Could you show me the error message and stacktrace?

Comment: it's the first line you posted throwing this error: `unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (521, 432). Other element would receive the click: <div id="busy" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; margin: 10% auto; left: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 200; overflow: visible;">...</div>`

Comment: @JOHN Is the page loaded? Do you add enough wait before click the button?

Comment: @JOHN May I access the application? It looks like the page displays a loading animation id='busy'. That element block the click so you cannot click at the dropdown button.

Comment: the webpage is https://www.freelance.de/project/create.php. You need an account (free), however, this is in German. I can also get you one.

Comment: @JOHN It is obvious that the page is still loaded when the first line is executed so it throws error. I've updated the answer with wait. Hope it helps.

Comment: At another point, it looks like this: `<select class="selectarea form-control bs-select-hidden" id="projecttype" name="projecttype" title="Bitte wählen" style="display: none;"><option class="bs-title-option" value="">Bitte wählen</option>
   
      <option value="" class="" selected="selected">Bitte wählen</option>
      <option value="1" class="">Inhouse-Projekt</option>
      <option value="2" class="" selected="selected">Kundenprojekt</option>      
     
     </select>`, the function given however doesn't work

Comment: @JOHN Structure of the projecttype dropdown is different from month. See my updated answer.